# how can i fix this fatal erreur while adding a page

Tags: wordpress, fatal-error, elementor

i have a wordpress website, and i can not modify anything or add any model or page, and when i try to add a page this error appears:

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Attempt to assign property "post_content" on null in /htdocs/wp-admin/includes/post.php:748 Stack trace: #0 /htdocs/wp-admin/post-new.php(66): get_default_post_to_edit('page', true) #1 {main} thrown in /htdocs/wp-admin/includes/post.php on line 748
'

i didn't try anthing yet to fix it
can you help me with it

Comment: have you got any solution for this issue. I am getting the  same error when try to add new post. i have PHP 8.1 and mariadb 10.6